# morris.js Graph container element not found

Tags: javascript, morris.js

Why am I getting an exception

> **Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found**

when using [`morris.js`](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/)?

Comment: When you want to share an answer on Stackoverflow, post your question describing the issue, then post the answer separately and mark it as the valid answer for your question. That way it'll get more exposure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Solution:** Put the javascript after the morris.js div

From this post from tiraeth:
https://github.com/morrisjs/morris.js/issues/137

Comment: When using with angularjs and a directive. you may wrap it in a $timeout.

Answer (score 9):

if don' t use the chart on this page, you can do this:

1. Go to the line where the exception is throwed in morris.js
2. change it like this:
   before:

   ```
     if (this.el === null || this.el.length === 0) {
      return;
       // throw new Error("Graph placeholder not found.");
     }
   ```

Comment: i want to add it in my code. where can i add this ?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I was using the node.js framework. Taking out the script tags containing the morris charts and the jquery from the bottom of the html file worked for me. I am using Require.js to load the dependencies for my project instead. I hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```html
<head>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="donut-example"></div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        Morris.Donut({
                            element: 'donut-example',
                            data: [
                              { label: "Download Sales", value: 12 },
                              { label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30 },
                              { label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20 }
                            ]
                        });
                    </script>

    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's code gets executed before the DOM contains #annual element. Put the javascript after the div or use jQuery.ready()

Answer (score 0):

I have copied some scripts containing `morris` implementation and had this problem. Apparently, the scripts are initializing 3 `morris` charts when in my `HTML` I only had implemented 1 element, so it was failing to initialize the bars for the unexisting elements