# datepicker enabling specific dates from database

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, datepicker

I am trying to enable only the dates that are in my database, after doing several research I came up with these code

These is my script

```js
 <script>
 <?php
 $dis = pg_query("SELECT 'date_purchased' FROM 'tree_solds';");
 foreach ($dis as $disa){
  $dis .="'".$disa."',";
  }
  $dis = substr($dis,0,-1);
 ?>
 
 var array=[<?php echo $dis; ?>];
 
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ maxDate: new Date(),
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
   if($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date), array) > -1)
   {
    return [true,"","Available"];
   }
    else{
    return [false,'',"Not Available"];
   }
   }
  });
 });
 </script>
```

and these is my html file

```html
<div><input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

When I query the console
the error that shows is these

```html
 GET http://localhost/resources/demos/style.css 
index.php:40 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
```

These is my line 37 to 40

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  
  <script>
 <?php
```

But currently when i click on the text box nothing shows. I've been looking at the code for several hours and can't seem to find any error.

Everything was working fine before I entered this part

```html
<?php
 $dis = pg_query("SELECT 'date_purchased' FROM 'tree_solds';");
 foreach ($dis as $disa){
  $dis .="'".$disa."',";
  }
  $dis = substr($dis,0,-1);
 ?>
 
 var array=[<?php echo $dis; ?>];
```

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Did you include jQuery and the datepicker libary?

Comment: @S.Pols : yes I did :)

Comment: Do you get any error in browser console?

Comment: @Jin Check the answer below and try it by removing the files which cause the error.

Comment: @SalmanA : yes it is executed as a php page

Answer (score 1):

Remove `maxDate: new Date()` from the initialization. Rather store the date in some variable and then set maxDate to that variable. Also remove that file which throws the error and try it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/yXMKC/1138/

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var array = ["2014-12-9", "2014-12-12", "2014-12-15"]; //for testing
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        //maxDate: new Date(),
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            if ($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date), array) > -1) {
                console.log('in')
                return [true, "", "Available"];
            } else {
                console.log('n')
                return [false, '', "Not Available"];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. These is the first code that I tried which worked, but what I am trying to achieve is to enable specific days selected from database and not from arrays :)

Comment: You can store database dates into the javascript array and use the same array inside beforeShowDay.

Comment: I think That's what I did from my code above :)?
I tried removing the maxDate but nothing happened.

Comment: @K K I didn't comment that to be rude, I was only asking since I don't see any difference from what I did, but remove the maxDate. Or maybe I  didn't understand. I'm still a beginner so... well

Comment: It's okay. I didn't took it that way. I was looking at the plugin morris. It appears that the plugin couldn't find the element and hence it throws the error which further stops the rest of javascript. See if you can disable the plugin and then try same code. Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176755/morris-js-graph-container-element-not-found