# Chart.js chart by passing data through the controller MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, chart.js

I am trying to display a chart by passing to it data from a controller. I am using chart.js

Model:

```
public class DatapointLine
{
    public DatapointLine(double x, double y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }

    // setting the name to be used when serializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "x")]
    public Nullable<double> X = null;

    //setting the name to be used whenserializing to JSON.
    [DataMember(Name = "y")]
    public Nullable<double> Y = null;
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult BarChart()
        {
            List<DatapointLine> dataPoints = new List<DatapointLine>{
                new DatapointLine(10, 22),
                new DatapointLine(20, 36),
                new DatapointLine(30, 42),
                new DatapointLine(40, 51),
                new DatapointLine(50, 46),
            };

            ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);

            return Json(dataPoints, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        var data = getData();
        AutoFollow(data);
    });

    function getData() {
        var dateValue = [];
        var countValue = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Supernethome/BarChart",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        }).done(function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(data) {
                dateValue.push(data.X);
                countValue.push(data.Y);
            });
        });
        return {
            dateValue: dateValue,
            countValue: countValue
        };
    }
        $(document).ready(function () {function AutoFollow(data) {
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx,
            {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    labels: data.dateValue, 
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'AutoFollow',
                            data: data.countValue, 
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,1)"
                        }, {
                            label: 'Manual',
                            data: [30, 29, 5, 5, 20, 3, 10],
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });
    }
    });
```

I am generating the views for the charts in partial views and then referencing the partial views in a main view.

I am getting the following errors:

> ```
> chartjs.init.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
>     at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chartjs.init.js:3)
>     at f (jquery.js:1026)
>     at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:1138)
>     at Function.ready (jquery.js:427)
>     at HTMLDocument.xt (jquery.js:97)
> ```

The error is eating a lot of time,Need Help.

Comment: For the first error: have you a `div` with an `id='mychart'`? The second error: I think you should use `data: data.d` in your Morris Area configuration. As for the third error, you should post the HTML/JavaScript code where the error is pointing.

Comment: @krlzlx Hi thanks a ton, adding .d worked, why is it necessary? Can you please elaborate on the third error please:). Thank you.

Comment: It was added in ASP.NET 3.5 version of ASP.NET AJAX to prevent cross site scripting attacks (can't find an official Microsoft link). [See this link](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/). For the third error, what is chartjs.init.js? Is it where you initialize Morris? If yes, you should post the code that generates the error in your question (around line 51 probably) to see what `getContext` is doing for example.

Comment: @krlzlx Hi, I had made a mistake, I am now trying using chart.js instead of morris.I have edited the details , getting the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chartjs.init.js:3)`, could you help me:)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like two different errors to me...

**Error 1 : Graph container element not found**

Checkout this thread as the issue sounds the same:

[morris.js Graph container element not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176755/morris-js-graph-container-element-not-found)

**Error 2 : Cannot read property 'getContext'**

This looks like a red herring. This exception is not being thrown by morris.js but by chartjs. However it may be that the exception thrown by this code is stopping the morris.js code from being executed successfully. As such it's worth testing the code in isolation i.e load up a view with nothing in it except the required morris scripts/assets and your inline script. No additional scripts or JavaScript libraries. Something like this :

**Example Test View**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="mychart"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Supernethome/BarChart", function (data) {
                new Morris.Area({
                element: 'mychart',
                data: data,
                xkey: 'X',
                ykeys: ['Y'],
                pointSize: 2,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true
            });

        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi like you said the vanilla seems to be working perfectly, however I need to integrate the graph to my custom theme, So how do I go about this?Is there a workaround. I tried the solutions provided in the thread to remove the graph container error, but still it persists. Also `<canvas id=""></canvas>` does not generate the graph but`<div id=""></div>` does. Why is this so?