# I Can't Hide/Show Textbox when radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is my html code & jquery, I want to hide the no. bpjs textbox when bpjs radio is checked. I don't think if my code is wrong, but i don't know why my code doesn't work.

```
                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Pengobatan</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="umum" onclick="w3.show('#nomor_bpjs')" name="pengobatan" class="minimal" value="Umum" value="<?= set_value('pengobatan') ?>">
                                    <label class="detail" for="umum">Umum</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
                                    <input type="radio" id="bpjs" onclick="w3.hide('#nomor_bpjs')" name="pengobatan" class="minimal" value="BPJS" value="<?= set_value('pengobatan') ?>">
                                    <label class="detail" for="bpjs">BPJS</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row" id="no_bpjs">
                            <label for="no_bpjs" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">No. BPJS </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nobpjs" name="nobpjs" placeholder="Masukan Nomor BPJS" value="<?= set_value('no_bpjs') ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**And my jquery**

```
        <script>
        $(function() {
            $('.nobpjs').hide();

            //show it when the checkbox is clicked
            $('input[id="bpjs"]').on('click', function() {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    //show div with class="nama"
                    $('.nobpjs').fadeIn();
                } else if ($('input[id="umum"]').on('click')) {
                    //hide div with class= "nama"
                    $('.nobpjs').hide();
                } else {
                    $('.nobpjs').hide();
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

I want to hide the no. bpjs textbox when bpjs radio is checked

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was calling your elements as a **class** instead of as a **id**.
In jQuery element IDs are called using `$('#idName')` and classes are called using `$('.className')`.

I fixed those mistakes in the code below and I also removed `onclick` attributes from the checkboxs.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
   <label class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">Pengobatan</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="umum" name="pengobatan" class="minimal" value="Umum" value="<?= set_value('pengobatan') ?>">
         <label class="detail" for="umum">Umum</label>
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
         <input type="radio" id="bpjs" name="pengobatan" class="minimal" value="BPJS" value="<?= set_value('pengobatan') ?>">
         <label class="detail" for="bpjs">BPJS</label>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row" id="no_bpjs">
   <label for="no_bpjs" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">No. BPJS </label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nobpjs" name="nobpjs" placeholder="Masukan Nomor BPJS" value="<?= set_value('no_bpjs') ?>">
   </div>
</div>
<script>
   $(function() {
       $('#nobpjs').hide();
   
       //show it when "nama" is clicked
       $('#bpjs').on('click', function() {
           if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
               $('#nobpjs').fadeIn();
           }
       });
       
       //Hide it when "umum" is clicked
       $('#umum').on('click', function() {
           if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
               //hides umum
               //$('#nobpjs').hide();
               $('#nobpjs').fadeOut(); //looks nice
           }
   
       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: hei, thanks for the answer. but it doesn't work in my program. i don't understand why, my textbox can't show when i check bpjs radio button.

Comment: My solution only works with the checkbox IDs. Compare mine code with yours, maybe you did a mistake somewhere.

Comment: i already compare, and i do the same like yours. but it doesn't work, i don't know why. do you have an idea?

Comment: Check your checkbox element, are you using `bpjs` as a class or ID?

Comment: i using `bpjs` as id

Comment: Did you remove the `onclick` attribute from the element?

Comment: yes, i have remove it

Comment: Check your Browser Console to check for error message.

Comment: I got this error message

Comment: Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found

Comment: The error was caused because your JavaScript code ran before the checkbox. Insert your JavaScript codes after the checkbox. If error persists insert your codes inside `jQuery.ready()` https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: it's also doesn't work

Comment: Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
d http://localhost/project1/client-1-rekammedis/assets/vendo/bower_component/morris.js/morris.min.js:6
c http://localhost/project1/client-1-rekammedis/assets/vendo/bower_component/morris.js/morris.min.js:6
d http://localhost/project1/client-1-rekammedis/assets/vendo/bower_component/morris.js/morris.min.js:6
<anonymous> http://localhost/project1/client-1-rekammedis/assets/vendo/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js:130

Comment: The error was caused by `morris.js`. Add your script after `morris.js` div. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18879173/8960497

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are trying to hide/show an element with **nobpjs** class but you don't have it in your html, instead you have an element with **nobpjs** id.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nobpjs"
```

Comment: I don't understand what's you mean. can you tell me detail?

Comment: $('.nobpjs') means you are selecting element with the class nobpjs. Check the html you've pasted, there is no element with the class nobpjs. Instead you have inout field with the id nobpjs. To select that field you need to change your jquery selector to $('#nobpjs') and then work with it. For example $('#nobpjs').hide(); Or add nobpjs class to the input field <input type="text" class="form-control nobpjs"

Comment: I already update to <input type="text" class="form-control nobpjs" and it's work to hide class nobpjs, but when i click bpjs radio button the textbox is not show. how i fix it?